# How to filter child collections and remove them based on a filter

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to filter the results of my child collection based on a boolean filter:

```
var result = from u in context.Users
             where u.Locations.Filter(x => x.IsActive)
```

Is this possible, I only see methods like .Any and .All which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you :

```
var result = (from u in context.Users
              select new
              {
                 u,
                 Locations = (from loc in u.Locations
                             where loc.IsActive
                             select loc),
              });
```

This will give you `Users` with active `Locations`